# how to get Ajax Success Function data in codeigniter

Tags: php, ajax

my ajax code

```
$.ajax({
          url : '<?php echo base_url('mobile_plan/getStates')?>',
          type: 'POST',
          data:{operator:operator},
          dataType:'json',
          success: function(response)
          {
              alert(response);
          }
       });
```

I am getting response in array for from controller now this ajax call is done from the same page in which I want response back in **PHP array** for further operating could you please guide me how it is possible. I am using **codeigniter 3.1**.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to send this response again to the controller in php you should create another **ajax** call with **POST** method and pass the response array as a data parameter.

Answer (score 0):

When using **ajax** it's recommended to pass data in **JSON** format.

In **PHP** you should do

```
echo json_endoce($data);
```

And in **Javascript**, in your `success` function

```
response = JSON.parse(response);
```

Comment: then how can i access response in php variable

Comment: how can i use response variable in php please let me know

Comment: @GauravDeshani It's not clear, you want to access response in PHP ? But response is **send** by PHP. Can you show your PHP code ?

Comment: actually  i am implmenting the module where mobile recharge plan will be display. for that i am passing operator,state name and plan in controller. now in controller there is an api for fetching the data. all the data are fetch sucessfully from api and sended back to the ajax as response.now i want to display response data back to the view page. the problem is ajax call is done on the same page.

Comment: @GauravDeshani I think I understand, so you want to get the data from the `success` function in `ajax` to the HTML page?
If yes, you can use `innerHTML` to add **text** to an element in the **HTML DOM**.